# Remove/modify completed user's task in Alfresco

Tags: javascript, alfresco, alfresco-webscripts

I have completed workflows's instance with ended users tasks in Alfresco 4.2.

I'd like to:

1. remove first completed task (without removing workflow's instance);
2. modify value properties of second completed task (for example, user's comment, owner and etc).

Is there easy way to make these actions in Alfresco, using for example, JS or internal web-scripts?

Early, I tried to modify task's properties using command in admin workflow console:

> update task activiti$100 bpm:comment="modified_comment"

but got error:

> org.alfresco.service.cmr.workflow.WorkflowException: 02225871 Failed
>   to update workflow task activiti$100, the task doesnt exist.

Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: So you are looking to modify an already completed process?

Comment: @Lista Yes, these tasks from already completed process.

Comment: And why are you trying to do this, is it some sort of migration?

Comment: its not sort of migration, its a question  of usability of system. Alfresco allows cancel completed process with associated tasks (for example, process of parallel approvement), but not particular completed task of this process.

Comment: Finally, I couldn't find the way to delete or update completed task of user. Therefore, I think I'll use cancelling workflow-instances in some cases.